# Accessing website through load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, weblogic

I am facing problem while accessing web site through load balancer but it work fine when I call website directly.

After getting traces I found my client is retransmitting TCP packet with PSH+ACK four times and after that load balancer send TCP packet with RST flag.

Before that my client send SYN and successfully got SYN+ACK.

Please help me to find out whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

We resolved issue, Our Load-balancer vendor just configure 7002 as http port and everything starts working fine.

Regards,
imran

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a session persistence problem.  Ask the network operator to disable one of the nodes in the pool, then retry.  If there *is* only one node in the pool and you still can't access, run traces going through the load balancer and traces going direct and compare.  You'll want to compare the http response headers.

Comment: Hi, i tried with one node and its same behavior.

Comment: You should get traces where it work and where it doesn't and compare.  You might also be able to use the HTTPFox extension inside Firefox to view request and response headers as well.

Comment: i check thru addon it shows request and response when i tried direct. But when i tried through load balancer it shows that it generate request but in header section no there was no request header.

Comment: Output of direct 
GET /session_manager/SessionManager?WSDL HTTP/1.1
Host: x.x:7002
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7
Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 12 Sep 2011 13:56:46 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1

Comment: Is your "direct to server" test hitting port 7002 and your "to load-balancer" test hitting port 7002 as well or does your load balancer listen on a different port?  (Also, what is your load-balancer?)

Comment: 1- Yes my direct to server test hitting port 7002
2- Yes to load-balancer also hitting 7002 and i can verify this by telnet command
3- I am using Nortel Alteon